# Javascript throw error - two script tags

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two script tags in my index.html. If I throw an error in the first script, it does break, but the second one still executes. Is it possible to prevent the second script from executing? I have to mention that I have no control over the second script, as it is dynamically generated (angular 2).

Comment: your question is loading to executing. once the angular is concern, it will bootstrap the application once it is available in the browser

Comment: In angular2 what is the build tool you are using, angular-cli, webpack, etc?

Comment: angular-cli (web pack version)

Comment: you first script is not part of the angular code?

Comment: No, it is not. In the first script I check for the IE version. If it is below 11, I want to show a message to the user that the browser is not supported.

Comment: The question is XY problem. There's no good way to do it the way you do. The most straightforward approach is to build them into a single script.

Comment: @estus, I'd like, but I'm not able to. Webpack bundles the whole angular 2 app in one script. I am trying to prevent the loading of this script if I detect a browse I know is not compatible with my app.

Comment: IMO you overcomplicate things. What will happen if both will be loaded? 1% of users will load some extra Kbs? You cannot do what you're asking, the only thing you can do is to add the second script tag programmatically from the first script. Again, this is XY problem. Doing browser checks in bundled app is the only reasonable way here. If you don't want to load the whole script at once, use Webpack chunks.